# ¿Cómo puedo editar un Crispy Form en Django?

Tags: html, python, css, django

Estoy aprendiendo a crear un website estilo blog utilizando Django, entonces como soy un principiante lo estoy haciendo por medios de "templates", como Bootstrap y Crispy Forms, mi problema es que, al hacer un Crispy Form, el lenguaje de los campos a rellenar es inglés, pero para este website me gustaría que los campos estén en Español, ya que va a ser de habla hispana. Entonces cuando creo un form que **se ve así**:

[image: Ejemplo 1]

Como pueden ver todo está en español excepto los campos para introducir los datos del usuario. Entonces me gustaría saber **cómo puedo editar esto para que salga en español**...

Así se ve el formulario en mi código:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="content-section">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">Inicie Sesión</legend>
                {{ form|crispy }}
            </fieldset>
            <div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Iniciar Sesión</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="border-top pt-3">
            <small class="text-muted">
                ¿No tiene una cuenta? <a class="ml-2" href='{% url 'register' %}'>Cree una cuenta.</a>
            </small>
        </div>
    </div>             
{% endblock content %}
```

Cualquier tipo de consejo o ayuda se apreciaría bastante.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución al problema.

Para cambiar el idioma de un formulario hecho en Crispy Forms, lo que hay que hacer es ir al archivo "forms.py" que es donde se encuentra la configuración de cada formulario, y añadir el siguiente código a la clase del formulario que deseemos cambiar, en este ejemplo voy a enseñar el de registración.

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
     email = forms.EmailField(
         label= 'Correo Electrónico',
         required=True,
     )
     username = forms.CharField(
         label = 'Nombre de Usuario',
         required=True,
     )
     password1 = forms.CharField(
         label = "Contraseña",
         required=True
     )
     password2 = forms.CharField(
         label = "Confirmar Contraseña",
         required=True
    )
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
```

Como pueden ver este es el formulario para registrarse, añadí el parámetro "label", y esto es lo que cambia el texto de cada campo. Este es el resultado que da:

[image: formulario cambiado]

Y para quitar los asteriscos que tenía previamente simplemente en mi archivo de estilos CSS y añadí esto al final:

```
  .asteriskField {
display: none;
```

}